# Как передать функцию из класса в структуру

Tags: c++, функции, классы, struct

Есть код, вида.

```
struct Command
{
    char const *text;
    void (*f)(void);
    bool active;
};

/* enumeration of objects - commands */
Command commands[]
{
    {"clearcom", clearCommandTerminal, false},
    {"dectop", desctop, true},
    {"deepsleep", powerSaveDeepSleep, true},
    {"systray", systemTray, true},
    {"app_desctop", _desc.window("f"), true}
};
```

Допустим есть класс, вида

```
class Application
{
    protected:
    private:
    public:
    void window(String name, void (*f1)(void), void (*f2)(void));
    void window();
};
```

Хочу реализовать механизм, при котором Пользователь создает объект класса `Application app;` далее его помещает в массив структур `Commands`, пример: `{"clearcom", app.clearCommandTerminal, false},`

Comment: Не очень понятно, что именно вам нужно — передать указатель на функцию-член (и тогда это что-то типа `void (Application::*f)(void);`, или передать функцию-член для *конкретного объекта* `app`, и тогда можно использовать, например, `bind`...

Comment: Да верно, передать функцию-член для конкретного объекта app

Comment: Если `clearCommandTerminal` - это нестатическая функция-член класса `Application`, тогда `Application app; Command commands[] { { "clearcom", std::bind(&Application::clearCommandTerminal, &app), false} };`

Answer (score 0):

Если `clearCommandTerminal` - это нестатическая функция-член класса `Application`, тогда

```
#include <functional>
Application app; 
Command commands[] 
{ 
    { "clearcom", std::bind(&Application::clearCommandTerminal, &app), false} 
};
```

Функция [std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) создаёт объект анонимного класса, содержащий оператор вызова, который вызывает функцию, переданную в качестве первого аргумента в `bind`. Вторым аргументом передан неявный первый параметр всех функций-членов класса: указатель `this`. Если функция, которую нужно вызвать, имеет явные параметры, то их можно указать следом.

Структуру `Command` придётся доработать, так как создаваемый функцией `bind` объект не имеет оператора преобразования к указателю на функцию.

```
struct Command
{
    char const *text;
    std::function<void(void)> f;
    bool active;
};
```

Если же это статическая функция, то можно просто передать указатель на неё:

```
Command commands[] 
{ 
    { "clearcom", &Application::clearCommandTerminal, false} 
};
```

Доработка структуры `Command` не требуется.